# Keyboard Events for nativescript-dev-appium

Tags: appium, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have created a PIN component where a user has to enter 6 digit PIN. I have designed this component by creating 6 Label components which shows mdi icon. In background i have a TextField which actually has focus and as user enters keys via keyboard, the Label text changes. I am trying to automate this use case using nativescript-dev-appium. Since the TextField is not visible, appium does not detect the same. I found that basic appium framework has methods to enter text via keyboard but same is not present with nativescript-dev-appium. Can someone suggest on how can i click on keyboard which is open on the page?

Here is how my PIN component on UI looks like

[image]

Please note that i am able to send the text properly when i try to do it in Record n play provided by Appium and it generates following code

```
await driver.longPressKeyCode(8, undefined, undefined)
```

however this function is not available for me when i use nativescript dev appium

Comment: Did you try finding the text field by it's automationText?

Comment: Yes. I viewed the source. However source does not show this since this textfield is not visible on screen. Its hidden

Comment: what do you mean by textfield is not visible on screen?

Comment: Does this also work on Android? I have a problem focussing a hidden TextField on Android, while on iOS it works fine.